# Soap request over tcpmon changes behaviour

Tags: java, web-services, apache, tcp, tcpmon

I am consuming a web service. I wrote a client with axis 1.4 using eclipse. I have access to webservices over ssl vpn. My axis client code works fine. However, code must be run on android device. I can not use axis code on android, because java rmi is not supported on android. I am trying to consume service with making httppost with apache httpclient library. In order to see axis request values, I used tcpmon. It helped me to write httppost code easily. The problem is that when I run code directly without using tcpmon it gives me the error below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument: setsockopt
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.setIntOption(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketSetOption(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.setOption(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.setOption(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.setTcpNoDelay(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.prepareSocket(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:254)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
at TTIncidentClient.main(TTIncidentClient.java:56)
```

If I send request over tcpmon it works. I get the response. I give you tcpmon output below:

REQUEST:

```
POST http://localhost:3333/SM/7/ws HTTP/1.1
SOAPAction: RetrieveList
Accept: application/soap+xml, application/dime, multipart/related, text/*
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Authorization: Basic bW9iaXNlbTpPeXAlPzIwMTM=
Content-Length: 456
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1
Host: 10.6.105.132:3333
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.5 (java 1.5)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><RetrieveIncidentListRequest xmlns="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7"><keys query="flag=true and category=&quot;incident&quot; and assignee.name=&quot;xx.yy&quot;"/></RetrieveIncidentListRequest></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

RESPONSE:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=AF8B0B75ED768852E44D7CB49DB5DD88; Path=/SM
Keep-Alive: timeout=1200000, max=1000
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2009
Date: Sun, 11 Aug 2013 22:12:17 GMT

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><RetrieveIncidentListResponse message="Success" returnCode="0" schemaRevisionDate="2012-11-12" schemaRevisionLevel="0" status="SUCCESS" xmlns="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7" xmlns:cmn="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7/Common" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.hp.com/SM/7 http://testsc:3333/SM/7/Incident.xsd">......</SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Normally I expect tcpmon behaviour must be same with my local but tcpmon changes the result. What can be the reason ?

Comment: Same thing occurs when I use eclipse tcp/ip monitor

Comment: I am searching proxy concept. I have little information about proxies. May the problem be related to this concept ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very interestingly, instead of using apache httpclient or java urlconnection libraries , I wrote socket programming code for soap as in [this](http://ashwinrayaprolu.wordpress.com/2008/09/15/soap-message-using-sockets/) example it worked. :)